# Getting a table cell's HTML, then removing certain elements from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Okay, for some reason, I can't quite seem to get what I need. I'm close, but for some reason can't quite put the last piece of the puzzle together.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/path/to/larger/image.jpg"><img src="/path/to/image.jpg"/></a>
      <br/>Some caption <a href="http://somesite.com">text</a>.
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  $('.fancy-gallery td > a').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).parent().html();
    $(this).attr('data-fancybox-title', title);
    $(this).attr('data-fancybox-group', 'group-' + $(this).closest('.textarea').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

So this gives me everything in the TD including the first anchor and image. I've tried using the .remove() and that didn't work, I've also tried using .not, and that also didn't work.

Basically what I need to do is remove the first `<a/>` tag and any line breaks (like `<br/>`). Then assign that to the data-fancybox-title attribute.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do `var title = $('.fancy-gallery td').text()`?

Comment: @KevinB Because I need to retain some of the html for anchors. I've just edited the HTML in the OP to reflect that there is potential to have HTML in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone the td, remove the anchor tag, then get the text.

```
$(function(){
  $('.fancy-gallery td').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).clone().find("a").remove().end().text();
    $(this).attr('data-fancybox-title', title);
    $(this).attr('data-fancybox-group', 'group-' + $(this).closest('.textarea').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the .text() removes the other html elements (like the anchor).

Comment: Did you not state in your question that you wanted to get the text without the anchor tag and other html elements? *"Basically what I need to do is remove the first <a/> tag and any line breaks (like <br/>). Then assign that to the data-fancybox-title attribute."* my solution gets said text without removing the anchor tag and other elements from the original.

Comment: Right, I need to remove the first anchor, but there may potentially be others. Check out my solution below. I'll mark yours as accepted since it got me going down the right path!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Thanks to @KevinB for helping get me started down the right path. Here is the answer for those looking to do the same:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fancy-gallery td').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).clone().find('a:has(img), br').remove().end().html();
        $(this).children('a').has('img').attr('data-fancybox-title', title).addClass($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text` instead of `.html`

```
var title = $(this).parent().text();
```

Comment: The problem is, I have links that I need to have in the title. So I need to retain some of the html, just not all of it.